# How to get the TempPath of a windows user, that is not the current one

Tags: c#, .net, registry, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows 2012 R2, user1: dev, user2: dev

In C# there is a method Path.GetTempPath(). user1 is a windows account and used as logon for running a service. In this service the TempPath is used.

The Application which is running via user2 want to know this path for some checks. How can i get this path?
How can i get the TempPath used by another windows account?

I tried the following:

```
 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("service");
 string serviceAccountName = RegistryHelpers.GetServiceAccountNameFromRegistry(sc);
 if (serviceAccountName.Equals("LocalSystem"))
                return null;

 // this is necessary for local accounts => Sid constructor throws exception
 serviceAccountName = serviceAccountName.Replace(@".\", @"");

 Sid sid = new Sid(serviceAccountName);

 string regKey = sid.SidString + @"\Environment";
 string tempPathValue = RegistryHelpers.GetRegistryValueFromRegistryUsers(regKey, "TEMP");
```

The Problem in this case is that the RegistryValue in SidString\Environment is "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp" which is leading to the windows user profile that is logged in currently.

Thanks and a happy new year, best wishes and so on.

Comment: If you want to share data between users then perhaps the temp directory is not the best place to store it?

Comment: I don't want to share data. I want to check if a virus detection solution is scanning this path.